# Can I ask a question for the purpose of providing an answer that I consider useful to all?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I am using both ubuntu and elementaryOS. The latter has a community that is active most on irc and google plus, so that, after a while, it is very hard to keep track of the problems and answers. That community is not very active on stackexchange, although it is welcome.

So, I would like to post here some of the main questions that I was confronted with in order to provide answers that would be easy to track by me and others.

(It is ok to do this on askubuntu - [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/111/47206).)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. This is okay on all of Stack Exchange. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer